# Passing arguments to OSGi application

Tags: osgi, command-line-arguments

I'm in a team that is converting a suite of Java applications to use OSGi. Previously, we used our own home-brew class loader system that has *some* similarities to OSGi, but it was nothing but trouble; we expect that by moving to using a system like Apache Felix we can have a system that works better while requiring less overall effort on our part to support.

We have been converting the modules that make up the applications into OSGi bundles, a largely painless affair with the use of Spring DM.
However, we — well, I as it's my responsibility in the team — need some way to reliably produce applications from this via a tool like Maven (or Jenkins); having a redistributable application installer that will install everything for the user is an absolute requirement. (We know our userbase fairly well; they want a simple install that won't download extra things after installation, well, not unless they decide to install extra plugins, but that's another story.) We do not wish to have to build the application manually at a console, or by using a GUI, as manual processes are too likely to run into silly human errors; we want to get it right and debugged *once*.

Moreover, some of the applications in our suite have to take command line arguments “like a conventional application”. (The application in question does significant processing internally, and sometimes needs to be invoked from other processes, such as web portals.) I know this causes some issues with the default Felix `main`, which only allows command line arguments for its own purposes instead of providing a way by default to export those to the bundles. (I know we could wrap things with a shell script so as to pass them in as properties, but… *ewwww…* there's got to be a better way. I suspect that making a custom `main` that exports a service providing access to the command line arguments is the best method.)

So, my question is what is a recommended way of building whole OSGi applications automatically, and am I using a reasonable approach to provide the command line arguments?

Comment: To be clear, I need to support an application interface that is not described in terms of anything vaguely like properties.

Comment: For future reference, just ask one question per posting.  If you had added a java tag to this (a much busier topic) it probably would have gotten closed pretty quickly as the questions being asked are not related to the same problem.

Comment: If you are starting something new, you might want to consider using Blueprint Services instead of Spring DM, since that is what Spring DM has become anyway.  You will just have to convert later when it is time to upgrade.  http://www.eclipse.org/gemini/blueprint/

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing your best option is to write your own main that does specifically what you want. Since OSGi R4.2 the launching API is standard and pretty straightforward. You can just start from Felix' Main since it is already generic (i.e., it can launch any R4.2 framework, such as Felix or Equinox) and change it how you wish.

If the command line args represent configuration properties, you could just push them into Config Admin. Otherwise, just expose them how you see fit.

Comment: +1. In the simplest case, writing your own `main` to launch OSGi in a standard way is just five lines of code: http://njbartlett.name/2011/03/07/embedding-osgi.html

Comment: @Neil: FWIW, I've already got most of that sort of thing working (and in fact, the answer is fairly similar to what I'm doing but haven't finished yet).

Comment: Also, you don't address how to do the packaging of the launcher with the bundles: that's important!

Answer (score 1):

The Apache Sling [Maven Launchpad Plugin](http://sling.apache.org/site/maven-launchpad-plugin.html) generates a finished OSGi app from a list of bundles to include, and the [Sling installer](http://sling.apache.org/site/jcr-installer-jcrjcrinstall-and-osgiinstaller.html) can be used to include initial configurations as well.

Even though they come from the Sling project, those module do not require your app to use the Sling app model, they are just used to build, launch and configure it.

Comment: An interesting suggestion. I shall investigate it further.

Comment: Should that say "do *not* require" instead? I was tempted to edit the answer, but I figured I should check with the author before inverting the meaning of what he wrote.

Comment: It doesn't _quite_ work; producing a JAR of the bundles is easy but merging that into the distribution archive just breaks the JAR in an odd way (making it work like it's simultaneously there but not, which utterly puzzles me even with `java -verbose`). Looks like I'll have to use shell scripting to build the bootstrap code.

Comment: @DonalFellows not sure what you mean by "merging that into the distribution archive" - the jar file generated by the Maven Launchpad Plugin is runnable, you can just start it with java -jar, no need to merge it with anything else if it contains all your bundles.

Answer (score 0):

For your arguments, use [metatype](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-metatype-service.html). It will allow your bundles to load with default values and when the user configures the bundle via the web console or config files, metatype will inject the values into your variables. An installer would also be able to set these values at install time via the config files.

Comment: It's not clear to me how that could apply to a list of files to process, as might be supplied by `theApp *.foo` (assuming POSIX command line processing rules) let alone some of the scenarios I've really got (which are rather ugly due to the legacy interface I've got to support; it's *not* just properties).

Comment: Metatype supports arrays and Vectors of most java primitives. What data are you passing that can't be represented with an array of primitives?

Comment: It's a mapping of names of input ports to a workflow to either files that supply the values to the workflow, or to literal values to use directly. The literals are not simple words; users like to do _nasty_ things. There's also a defaulting mechanism and… well, the details are complicated (legacy interface) and not really too germane. It would be simpler if this was a tool targeted mainly at programmers, where we could just tell them to use a scripting language (e.g., JRuby) to configure things. But it isn't.

Comment: Also, a general property mechanism isn't _discoverable_ — users will only figure it out by googling for blogs or other silly things like that — so making a discoverable command line that doesn't bind exactly what things are acceptable into the launcher itself requires a different approach.

Comment: Googling for blogs? Metatype allows you to define configuration properties in your Karaf Web Console. Unless your users can't fill out a simple config GUI that you define yourself, there's no googling required. I think we stopped talking about the same thing a while ago.

Comment: The users _can't_ fill out a simple config GUI. The code's being used in circumstances where there is no GUI.

Comment: Ah, if any of that had been in the question, I wouldn't have proposed this answer :)