# OSGi service reference is null (service from launcher to bundle)

Tags: java, osgi, apache-felix

I need to pass some parameters from felix launcher class (Main) to bundle and I followed [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10714502/3505403). What I did

**Launcher project**
test.launcher package contains:Main.java,Temp.java,TempI.java

**Bundle project**
test.bundle package contains:Activator.java
test.launcher package contains:TempI.java

As you can see I copied TempI.java to bundle project as launcher is not bundle and can't export its packages.

In Main

```
BundleContext context = felix.getBundleContext();
ServiceRegistration serviceRegistration=context.registerService(TempI.class.getName(),  new Temp(), null);
```

In Activator

```
ServiceReference serviceReference = context.getServiceReference(TempI.class.getName());
TempI service = (TempI) context.getService(serviceReference); 
System.out.println(service.testService());
```

but I get in Activator

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Specified service reference cannot be
>   null.

What is the problem? Again different classloaders? Or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You state that both the launcher and the bundle contain their own copies of the TempI class. One is loaded by the classloader of the launcher and the other by the classloader of the bundle. To the VM and therefore the OSGi service registry, these are different Class objects. So when you bundle looks for a TempI service which is of the TempI class known to your bundle, it finds none.

You need to not put TempI in your bundle and instead import the package. You also need to configure the framework to export the package using [org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/Constants.html#FRAMEWORK_SYSTEMPACKAGES_EXTRA). Then you bundle will import the package from the system bundle and the service registered in the launcher will be visible to the bundle.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I think it's what I was looking for. I was not sure if two copies of one interface are the same that's why in my question I described the packages. If you have time could you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22963720/osgi-felix-ignores-osgi-inf ?